# jQuery: Detect XHR() delay

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

What's the best method, to **detect a delayed XHR request** (`jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.load()`), that **isn't a timeout** (after x-seconds)?

I'm looking for a solution to display a wait message for user interface (connection abort).

Comment: A delayed XHR request? Ajax requests are made immediately by the browser unless you wrapped the call inside a setTimeout(function(){}, timeout);. If you are not doing that then look at ajaxBeforeSend event in jQuery which gets dispatched just before the ajax call is made and you have the option to abort it. Another option is for you to set a timeout in the call itself. Pass the "timeout" object with a timeout in ms and jQuery will call the error handler that you supplied it with when the timeout value reaches after the call is made.